# Watching multiple repos in Bamboo in one plan

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bamboo, build-tools, build-system

I am new to build systems and have to work on bamboo. I wrote a pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve and want to know if it is doable:

```
let repoA = Main app 
let repoB = Component of Main app 

Scenario 1: I commit to a branch in repoA
I checkout repoA [branch]
I build repoA
I check out repoB [master]
I build repoB into repoA
END

Scenario 2: I commit to a branch in repoB
I checkout repoA [master]
I build repoA
I check out repoB [branch]
I build repoB into repoA
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In bamboo that it is possible to achieve that with with two build steps. The whole plan can be set to be triggered by either repoA or repoB in the trigger setting.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide more detail or examples?  Short replies like this one are better suited to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's doable. If in `Plan configuration` you:

- add both repos in `Repositories` tab
- add 'repository trigerred' trigger (with both repos) in tab `Triggers`
- add both branches in `Branches` tab (can be set to be done automatically with branch creation)

then

- pushing commit to branch in repoA will trigger run of this plan with version of repoA from branch and master from repoB (Scenario 1)
- pushing commit to branch in repoB will trigger run of this plan with version of repoB from branch and master from repoA (Scenario 2)